# createsuperuser django openshift v3

Tags: python, django, django-admin, openshift, openshift-nextgen

How can I do some managing works such as `createsuperuser` ,`makemigrations`, `migrate` ect in **OpenShift-NextGen** for a Django Application ? (Step-by-Step)

In **OpenShift-V2**, I did the same by login to shell by `rhc ssh app_name` and run the command python `$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/wsgi/myproject/manage.py createsuperuser` ([Reference](https://github.com/openshift/django-example/blob/master/README.md#admin-user-name-and-password))

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

Step 1: Login to OpenShift-V3 using `oc login`
Step 2: Select your project using `oc project <project_name>`
Step 3: List your all pods using  `oc get pods`
It would be something like this,

```
NAME                     READY     STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
django-example-4-build   0/1       Completed   0          1h
django-example-5-build   0/1       Completed   0          1h
django-example-6-i0omn   1/1       Running     0          1h
```

Step 4: Find out the name which is at Running state.
Step 5: Run the command, `oc rsh <Name_of_the_pod_at_running_state>`
In my case it is, `oc rsh django-example-6-i0omn`
Step 6: Then, run `python manage.py createsuperuser` to create super user

**Method 2**


Step 1:Login to your OpenShift-v3 using [**Web-Console**](https://console.preview.openshift.com/console/)
Step 2:Go to `Dashboard`
Step 3:Select pods by `Application -> Pods`
Step 4:Choose the pod which is at running state
Step 5:Choose `Terminal` tab
Step 6:Then, run `python manage.py createsuperuser` to create super user

Hope, It will work for you :)